# Roll a 6-sided fair die until a 6 appears. Let X = the number of 1's that are rolled. Find Var(X).

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expectation

Let X = the number of 1's that are rolled. Find E[X] and Var(X).

I can't seem to calculate Var(X).

I've calculated E[X] = 1.

I let R = the number of non-6 rolls, and I let Y = the number of rolls . R + 1 = Y. E[R + 1] = E[Y]. E[R] = E[Y] - 1. E[Y] = 6 because Y ~ Geom(1/6), so E[R] = 5.

R = $R_1 + R_2 + R_3 + R_4 + R_5$, where $R_i$ = the number of times face i has been rolled. All the $R_i$'s are identically distributed, so E[Y] = E[$R_1$] = 1/5E[R] = 1.

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance If you still don't get it, I (or somebody)'ll answer.

Answer (score 1):

For roll $i$, let $X_i=1$ if roll $i$ of the die is 1 and 0 otherwise. Hence,
$$R_1 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^R X_i$$

The dice cannot roll 6 in the first $R$ rolls, so $X_i=1$ with probability 1/5 and 0 with probability 4/5. Hence, $$E[R_1|R] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^R E[X_i|R] = \frac{1}{5}R$$

$$Var[R_1|R] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^R Var[X_i|R] = \frac{1}{5}\frac{4}{5}R$$

By the law of total variance,
\begin{align*}
Var[R_1] &= Var[E[R_1|R]] + E[Var[R_1|R]]\\
         &= Var[\frac{R}{5}] + E[\frac{4}{25}R]\\
         &= \frac{1}{25}Var[R] + \frac{4}{25}E[R]\\
         &= \frac{1}{25}\frac{1-1/6}{1/36} + \frac{4}{25}5\\
         &= 2
\end{align*}

Comment: $\def\E{\mathsf E}\def\V{\mathsf{Var}}$Let $Y$ be the number of rolls *before* the first `6`; a Shifted Geometric Distribution.$$Y\sim\mathcal{Geo}_0(1/6)\\\E(Y)=5\\\V(Y)=30$$Now under the condition of $Y$, $X$ is the count of `1`s that occur among $Y$ iid trials when given none of those trials are `6`; a Binomial Distribution$$X\mid Y\sim\mathcal{Bin}(Y,1/5)\\\E(X\mid Y)=Y/5\\\V(X\mid Y)=4Y/25$$Then it is just a matter of applying the Laws of Total Expectation and Variance: $$\begin{align}\E(X)&=\E(\E(X\mid Y))\\[2ex]\V(X)&=\E(\V(X\mid Y))+\V(\E(X\mid Y))\end{align}$$